# Image stats from Filepicker/Filestack

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io, filepicker

Is it possible to get the size and dimensions of an image that was uploaded through FilePicker using the ID assigned to each image by filepicker?
For example, make a request to the service by sending the id and receive this information in any way?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use stat to get more detailed metadata of an uploaded file:

https://www.filestack.com/docs/file-ingestion/javascript-api/stat

```
filepicker.stat(
  blob,
 {
width: true,
height: true
},
function(metadata){
console.log(JSON.stringify(metadata));
}
);
```